# Ordering subsections of case statement

Tags: sql, sqlite, select, sql-order-by

So I have a query with the following sort order:

```
String sortOrder = "CASE " + ICCGoal.COLUMNS.category
        + " WHEN '" + GoalCategory.PHYSICAL_ACTIVITY.getEncodedValue() + "' THEN 1"
        + " WHEN '" + GoalCategory.SLEEP.getEncodedValue() + "' THEN 2"
        + " WHEN '" + GoalCategory.SOCIAL.getEncodedValue() + "' THEN 3"
        + " WHEN '" + GoalCategory.MOOD.getEncodedValue() + "' THEN 4"
        + " WHEN '" + GoalCategory.ENERGY.getEncodedValue() + "' THEN 5"
        + " END";
```

is there anyway to order the sections of the returned values?

Currently, I have all goals of "SLEEP" type returned after the "PHYSICAL_ACTIVITY" and before "SOCIAL" goals, in whatever order they are stored.

Would it be possible to return them ordered by date created? Or just ordered in another way than default?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add a secondary sorting criteria:

```
String sortOrder = "CASE " + ICCGoal.COLUMNS.category
        + " WHEN '" + GoalCategory.PHYSICAL_ACTIVITY.getEncodedValue() + "' THEN 1"
        + " WHEN '" + GoalCategory.SLEEP.getEncodedValue() + "' THEN 2"
        + " WHEN '" + GoalCategory.SOCIAL.getEncodedValue() + "' THEN 3"
        + " WHEN '" + GoalCategory.MOOD.getEncodedValue() + "' THEN 4"
        + " WHEN '" + GoalCategory.ENERGY.getEncodedValue() + "' THEN 5"
        + " END" // Original ordering from the OP
        + ", date_created"; // Secondary term
```

Comment: Awesome. Such a simple solution. I didn't know you could chain other criteria with commas. Thanks very much.